# How to write dot products as <v, w>?

Tags: symbols

In my class, we write dot products like <v, w>, but the < and > on LaTeX are too stretched out and become too close to the adjacent elements.

The symbol is used in the cover of [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Te8eL5r7aJs)

Comment: `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use `\langle` and `\rangle`:

$\langle u,v\rangle$

Those are standard LaTeX commands used for duality brackets or Dirac brackets.